# Probability of (A u B u C)?

Tags: probability

Event A and B are independent, A and C are mutually exclusive, B and C are independent. Given:

- $\Pr(A) = 1/2$
- $\Pr(B) = 1/4$
- $\Pr(C) = 1/8$

Find $P(A \cup B \cup C)$ ?

The teacher gave the answer to be $23/32$. I got $47/64$, not quite sure if I'm doing the right thing.

Ps. $Pr(A \cap B \cap C)$ is ?

Comment: You could edit into your answer how you got to $47.64$; this would help others identify why your answer differs from your teacher's.

Comment: $P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$ because $A$ and $C$ cannot happen simultaneously.

Comment: Have you covered inclusion-exclusion in class?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a Venn diagram?

Comment: I got the drift now. Thank you all for the help. Y'all rock.

Comment: The principle of [Inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) can be helpful here. Teachers are mostly correct. No exception here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A\cup C)+P(B)-P(B\cap (A\cup C))=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P((A\cap B) \cup (B\cap C))=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A)P(B)-P(B)P(C)+P((A\cap B) \cap (B\cap C)$$

The last term is $0$, so we get

$$P(A\cup B\cup C)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{32}=\frac{23}{32}$$

Answer (score 0):

A venn diagram should certainly help you solve this problem!

One of the property of Independent events is that the probability of their intersection is a product of their individual probabilities. So, $P(A \cap B)$ is $P(A) \times P(B)$. Whereas for mutually exclusive events, the probability of intersection is $0$ as they can't both occur simultaneously!

$$ P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$$

Can you take from here? It shouldn't be so hard to get the right answer.

Comment: i got the drift and I marveled at the mystery of Mathis, but it makes sense now. Thank you very much.